# Can`t run spark app because of java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/postgresql/Driver

Tags: java, postgresql, apache-spark

I can`t run mt Spark app because  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/postgresql/Driver

I did same like [How can I connect to a postgreSQL database into Apache Spark using scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24916852/how-can-i-connect-to-a-postgresql-database-into-apache-spark-using-scala) but when I try to start my app I get this Exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/postgresql/Driver
    at SparkRecommendationMatrix.<init>(SparkRecommendationMatrix.scala:31)
    at Main$.main(Main.scala:26)
    at Main.main(Main.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.launch(SparkSubmit.scala:292)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 10 more
```

My bild.sbt file:

```
name := "untitled12"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.2-1003-jdbc4",
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-mllib_2.10" % "1.0.0"
)

resolvers += "Akka Repository" at "http://repo.akka.io/releases/"
```

and my java code

```
val classes = Seq(
    getClass, // To get the jar with our own code.
    classOf[org.postgresql.Driver] // To get the connector.
  )

  val jars = classes.map(_.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath())

  // set up environment
  val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName(name).setJars(jars)
  //.setMaster("spark://192.168.10.122:7077")
  val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
```

Comment: It's quite obvious: you apparently do **not** have the Postgres JDBC driver available to your Spark application/installation.  Jens answer is absolutely correct.

Comment: Maybe this is caused by the fact that the current 9.2 driver has the build number `1004` not `1003`?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you every figure out a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem. Solved it by passing `postgresql.jar` as a parameter of spark-submit:

```
spark-submit --class <<class>> --jars /full_path_to/postgressql.jar My_File.jar
```