# Using pyspark to connect to PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to connect to a database with pyspark and I am using the following code:

```
sqlctx = SQLContext(sc)
df = sqlctx.load(
    url = "jdbc:postgresql://[hostname]/[database]",
    dbtable = "(SELECT * FROM talent LIMIT 1000) as blah",
    password = "MichaelJordan",
    user =  "ScottyPippen",
    source = "jdbc",
    driver = "org.postgresql.Driver"
)
```

and I am getting the following error:

[image]

Any idea why is this happening?

**Edit**: I am trying to run the code locally in my computer.

Answer (score 43):

Download the PostgreSQL JDBC Driver from https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download/

Then replace the database configuration values by yours.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Python Spark SQL basic example") \
    .config("spark.jars", "/path_to_postgresDriver/postgresql-42.2.5.jar") \
    .getOrCreate()

df = spark.read \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/databasename") \
    .option("dbtable", "tablename") \
    .option("user", "username") \
    .option("password", "password") \
    .option("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver") \
    .load()

df.printSchema()
```

More info: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html

Comment: This one works! 
I was running my code in jupyter lab. I tried stoping and restarting `spark` session, but  it didnt load. When I restarted jupyter kernel, it worked!

Comment: It doesn't work for me, it still gives "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver" Any idea?

Comment: For me it gives the following error:
`: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.`
My postgres db has a name. And i dont see an option to include that in the syntax. However when i use the `psycopg2` library it works.
Is there any way I can make the spark connect directly?

Comment: Can the url, usrname and pass be added to the config of the SparkSession so that spark can let me just do `spark.sql('select * from db.tblname limit 10')` ?

Comment: The url changed to https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download/, could you please update it?

Comment: @thentangler Check your postgresql configuration file. If using Ubuntu the file is under  ```/etc/postgresql/*/main/postgresql.conf```

Local system access for all users should have a line that resembles this: ```host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5```

Comment: getting the following error. Do I need to install hadoop?
24/01/03 12:49:00 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: HADOOP_HOME and hadoop.home.dir are unset. -see https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/WindowsProblems

Answer (score 19):

The following worked for me with postgres on localhost:

Download the PostgreSQL JDBC Driver from https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html.

For the `pyspark` shell you use the `SPARK_CLASSPATH` environment variable:

```sh
$ export SPARK_CLASSPATH=/path/to/downloaded/jar
$ pyspark
```

For submitting a script via `spark-submit` use the `--driver-class-path` flag:

```bash
$ spark-submit --driver-class-path /path/to/downloaded/jar script.py
```

In the python script load the tables as a `DataFrame` as follows:

```py
from pyspark.sql import DataFrameReader

url = 'postgresql://localhost:5432/dbname'
properties = {'user': 'username', 'password': 'password'}
df = DataFrameReader(sqlContext).jdbc(
    url='jdbc:%s' % url, table='tablename', properties=properties
)
```

or alternatively:

```py
df = sqlContext.read.format('jdbc').\
    options(url='jdbc:%s' % url, dbtable='tablename').\
    load()
```

Note that when submitting the script via `spark-submit`, you need to define the `sqlContext`.

Answer (score 8):

To use pyspark and jupyter notebook notebook: first open pyspark with

```
pyspark --driver-class-path /spark_drivers/postgresql-42.2.12.jar  --jars /spark_drivers/postgresql-42.2.12.jar
```

Then in jupyter notebook

```
import os
jardrv = "~/spark_drivers/postgresql-42.2.12.jar"


from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.config('spark.driver.extraClassPath', jardrv).getOrCreate()
url = 'jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1/dbname'
properties = {'user': 'usr', 'password': 'pswd'}
df = spark.read.jdbc(url=url, table='tablename', properties=properties)
```

Comment: FWIW, I was not able to get any of the below solutions to work without specifying --driver-class-path and --jars directly to pyspark. This is the correct answer

Comment: I could not get it to work on Zeppelin notebook on AWS, but it worked when i ssh'ed into the master EC2 node and used pyspark --driver-class-path /spark_drivers/postgresql-42.2.12.jar  --jars /spark_drivers/postgresql-42.2.12.jar. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

It is necesary copy postgresql-42.1.4.jar in all nodes... for my case, I did copy in the path /opt/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/jars

Also, i set classpath in ~/.bashrc (export SPARK_CLASSPATH="/opt/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/jars" )

and work fine in pyspark console and jupyter

Comment: I'm looking for how to do this in Amazon EMR. It used to work for me just setting spark.jar=/path/to/driver but after EMR 5.2.1 (which was Spark version 2.0.2) I can't get it to work anymore.

Answer (score 4):

You normally need either:

1. to install the Postgres Driver on your cluster,
2. to provide the Postgres driver jar from your client with the --jars option
3. or to provide the maven coordinates of the Postgres driver with --packages option.

If you detail how are you launching pyspark, we may give you more details.

Some clues/ideas:

[spark-cannot-find-the-postgres-jdbc-driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26214597/cant-run-spark-app-because-of-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-postgresql-dr)

[Not able to connect to postgres using jdbc in pyspark shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29669420/not-able-to-connect-to-postgres-using-jdbc-in-pyspark-shell)

Comment: What if I am trying to run it locally? Do I need to download the postgres driver? and where should I store it?

Comment: Yes, you need it. Because you're acting as a Postgres client and you're specifying that you're going to use the Postgres driver in the "driver = "org.postgresql.Driver"" option. You can store it wherever you want in your local computer (for example jre\lib\ext of your java installation) and specify the storage path in the CLASSPATH.

Answer (score 3):

One approach, building on the example per the [quick start guide](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html), is [this blog post](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/exercises/spark-exercise-dataframe-jdbc-postgresql.html) which shows how to add the `--packages org.postgresql:postgresql:9.4.1211` argument to the `spark-submit` command.

This downloads the driver into `~/.ivy2/jars` directory, in my case `/Users/derekhill/.ivy2/jars/org.postgresql_postgresql-9.4.1211.jar`.  Passing this as the `--driver-class-path` option gives the full spark-submit command of:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.0.2/bin/spark-submit\
 --packages org.postgresql:postgresql:9.4.1211\
 --driver-class-path /Users/derekhill/.ivy2/jars/org.postgresql_postgresql-9.4.1211.jar\
 --master local[4] main.py
```

And in `main.py`:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

dataframe = spark.read.format('jdbc').options(
        url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/my_db?user=derekhill&password=''",
        database='my_db',
        dbtable='my_table'
    ).load()

dataframe.show()
```

Answer (score 3):

I also get this error

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(Unknown Source)
```

and add one item `.config('spark.driver.extraClassPath', './postgresql-42.2.18.jar')` in `SparkSession` - that worked.

eg:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
import os
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName('Python Spark Postgresql') \
    .config("spark.jars", "./postgresql-42.2.18.jar") \
    .config('spark.driver.extraClassPath', './postgresql-42.2.18.jar') \
    .getOrCreate()


df = spark.read \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/abc") \
    .option("dbtable", 'tablename') \
    .option("user", "postgres") \
    .option("password", "1") \
    .load()

df.printSchema()
```

Comment: I tried using .config('spark.driver.extraClassPath', './postgresql-42.2.18.jar') and it still did not work.

Answer (score 2):

I had trouble to get a connection to the postgresDB with the jars i had on my computer.
This code solved my problem with the driver

```
 from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
 import os

 sparkClassPath = os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages org.postgresql:postgresql:42.1.1 pyspark-shell'

 spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .config("spark.driver.extraClassPath", sparkClassPath) \
    .getOrCreate()

 df = spark.read \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/yourDBname") \
    .option("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver") \
    .option("dbtable", "yourtablename") \
    .option("user", "postgres") \
    .option("password", "***") \
    .load()

df.show()
```

Comment: Many many thanks! I was using the config approach too and had a good while to figure out that ```.option("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver") \```is mandatory for that approach.

Answer (score 1):

This exception means jdbc driver does not in driver classpath.
you can spark-submit jdbc jars with `--jar` parameter, also add it into driver classpath using `spark.driver.extraClassPath`.

Answer (score 1):

1. Download postgresql jar from [here](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html):
2. Add this to ~Spark/jars/ folder.
3. Restart your kernel.
   It should work.

Answer (score 0):

Just initialize pyspark with `--jars <path/to/your/jdbc.jar>`

E.g.: `pyspark --jars /path/Downloads/postgresql-42.2.16.jar`

then create a dataframe as suggested above in other answers

E.g.:

```
df2 = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url", "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db").option("dbtable", "yourTableHere").option("user", "postgres").option("password", "postgres").option("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver").load()
```

Answer (score 0):

Download postgres JDBC driver from https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html
and use the script below.
Changes to make:

1. Edit PATH_TO_JAR_FILE
2. Save your DB credentials in an environment file and load them
3. Query the DB using query option and limit using fetch size

```
import os
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

PATH_TO_JAR_FILE = "/home/user/Downloads/postgresql-42.3.3.jar"
spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Example") \
    .config("spark.jars", PATH_TO_JAR_FILE) \
    .getOrCreate()

DB_HOST = os.environ.get("PG_HOST")
DB_PORT = os.environ.get("PG_PORT")
DB_NAME = os.environ.get("PG_DB_CLEAN")
DB_PASSWORD = os.environ.get("PG_PASSWORD")
DB_USER = os.environ.get("PG_USERNAME")

df = spark.read \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", f"jdbc:postgresql://{DB_HOST}:{DB_PORT}/{DB_NAME}") \
    .option("user", DB_USER) \
    .option("password", DB_PASSWORD) \
    .option("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver") \
    .option("query","select * from your_table") \
    .option('fetchsize',"1000") \
    .load()

df.printSchema()
```