# Digesting an month of Reddit Comments

Tags: python, json, postgresql

I have two large json files representing one month's worth of Reddit Comments (37gb) and Reddit Submissions (16gb)

I want to pull them into a postgres installation on my local win7 machine.

My naive approach was to use `psycopg2.extras.DictCursor`.  I built a large list of dicts created from loading each json object from the file.  Then perform a `cur.executemany(insert_sql, json_dicts)`

This works,  but I don't think it scales.  The json_dicts object will be enormous before it's time to execute.

I've been thinking how to write a scaleable script for this.

First, I suspect that it's fine to read through the entire json file -- that it won't explode memory?

I am processing it as:

```
with open(fp[foo], encoding="utf-8") as f:

    for line in f:
        j_content = json.loads(line)
```

If that's true, then I can just do batched commits (say commit every time I accumulate 100k objects).  If I wrap it in `try` nicely, then I ought to be able to see any point I have a failure and restart from that point the next time i try to process.

I'm asking for better advice on how to digest this stuff - I have no experience wrangling files this large.

I suppose too there might be some optimizations I should do on the postgres side to make this database manageable?

Comment: While you avoid reading all file at once ( like `.read()`, `.readlines()` or `list(f)` etc ) - you can do not worry about memory, unless line is so huge, that it even could not be processed itself

Answer (score 0):

There's a wonderful engine called spark (which also has a python api, pyspark) which can generally handle datasets that are too big to fit in memory and can load json objects. It's a bit of a pain to install on win7 but it looks like there's a [postgres package([Using pyspark to connect to PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34948296/using-pyspark-to-connect-to-postgresql))  that you can download and use in conjunction with spark to do what you're asking. Its currently very popularily used in many industries because of how easily scalable it is.