# Out Of Memory Error while reading 400 thousand rows in Spark SQL

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have some data on postgres and trying to read that data on spark dataframe but i get error `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded`. I am using PySpark with RAM of 8GB.

Below is the code

```
import findspark
findspark.init()
from pyspark import SparkContext, SQLContext
sc = SparkContext()
sql_context = SQLContext(sc)
temp_df = sql_context.read.format('jdbc').options(url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/database",
            dbtable="table_name",
            user="user",
            password="password",
            driver="org.postgresql.Driver").load()
```

I very new to world of spark. I tried same with python pandas which worked without any issue but with spark i got error.

```
Exception in thread "refresh progress" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
at scala.collection.immutable.VectorBuilder.<init>(Vector.scala:713)
at scala.collection.immutable.Vector$.newBuilder(Vector.scala:22)
at scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq$.newBuilder(IndexedSeq.scala:46)
at scala.collection.generic.GenericTraversableTemplate$class.genericBuilder(GenericTraversableTemplate.scala:70)
at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.genericBuilder(Traversable.scala:104)
at scala.collection.generic.GenTraversableFactory$GenericCanBuildFrom.apply(GenTraversableFactory.scala:57)
at scala.collection.generic.GenTraversableFactory$GenericCanBuildFrom.apply(GenTraversableFactory.scala:52)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.builder$1(TraversableLike.scala:229)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:233)
at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
at org.apache.spark.ui.ConsoleProgressBar$$anonfun$3.apply(ConsoleProgressBar.scala:89)
at org.apache.spark.ui.ConsoleProgressBar$$anonfun$3.apply(ConsoleProgressBar.scala:82)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:285)
at org.apache.spark.ui.ConsoleProgressBar.show(ConsoleProgressBar.scala:82)
at org.apache.spark.ui.ConsoleProgressBar.org$apache$spark$ui$ConsoleProgressBar$$refresh(ConsoleProgressBar.scala:71)
at org.apache.spark.ui.ConsoleProgressBar$$anon$1.run(ConsoleProgressBar.scala:56)
at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
Exception in thread "RemoteBlock-temp-file-clean-thread" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
at
org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$RemoteBlockDownloadFileManager.org$apache$spark$storage$BlockManager$RemoteBlockDownloadFileManager$$keepCleaning(BlockManager.scala:1648)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$RemoteBlockDownloadFileManager$$anon$1.run(BlockManager.scala:1615)
2018-11-12 21:48:16 WARN  Executor:87 - Issue communicating with driver in heartbeater
org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeoutException: Futures timed out after [10 seconds]. This timeout is controlled by spark.executor.heartbeatInterval
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.org$apache$spark$rpc$RpcTimeout$$createRpcTimeoutException(RpcTimeout.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:58)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:36)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEndpointRef.askSync(RpcEndpointRef.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$reportHeartBeat(Executor.scala:785)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anon$2$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(Executor.scala:814)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anon$2$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Executor.scala:814)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anon$2$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Executor.scala:814)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1992)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anon$2.run(Executor.scala:814)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [10 seconds]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:219)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:223)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:201)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
    ... 14 more
2018-11-12 21:48:16 ERROR Executor:91 - Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
2018-11-12 21:48:16 ERROR SparkUncaughtExceptionHandler:91 - Uncaught exception in thread Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 0,5,main]
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
2018-11-12 21:48:16 WARN  TaskSetManager:66 - Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

2018-11-12 21:48:16 ERROR TaskSetManager:70 - Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
```

My end goal is to do some processing on large database tables using spark. Any help would be great.

Comment: Post your code, it will help us understand exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: @AmarGajbhiye i added code please have a look

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry but it seems that your RAM isn't enough. Also, spark is intended to work on distributed systems with large amounts of data (clusters), so maybe it isn't the best option for what you are doing.

Kind regards

**EDIT**
As @LiJianing suggested, you can increase the spark executor memory.

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
conf = (SparkConf().set("spark.executor.memory", "8g"))
sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)
```

Comment: can you guide me how i can move data from Postgres to spark environment, any tutorial.

Comment: You can move the data from `Postgres` to `Hive` using `Sqoop` and process it using `Spark`, right? You can, https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/14802/sqoop-importexport-tutorial.html

Comment: Assuming you are using scala, i've found something you might like. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24916852/how-can-i-connect-to-a-postgresql-database-into-apache-spark-using-scala

Comment: 400K rows is nothing though.

Comment: setting executer memory 8g also giving error

Comment: Can you post the error ? Maybe try to lower the value, try 6gb.

Comment: It seems happening due to data being loaded into one partition. why don't you use partition column and lower bound and upper bound limit and specify number of partitions to make your connection execute in parallel and also to uniformly distribute your data.  Please try like this.  temp_df = sql_context.read.format('jdbc').options(url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/database",dbtable="table_name",user="user",password="password",partitionColumn="Partition column",lowerBound=lower limit,upperBound=upper limit,numPartitions=number of partitions)driver="org.postgresql.Driver").load()

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see your code, but just increase the memory of executor, eg. spark.python.worker.memory

Comment: i added code..please have a look

Comment: i am not very familar with pyspark, but i think you'd better try to set spark.python.worker.memory=6g